# Is there a rails way to get current route's scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

If you have a scope in your routes.rb file such as:

```
scope "/account" do
  resources :items
end
```

How can you determine if the current page is in the 'account' section? Meaning the following items would be considered in the 'accounts' section?

```
/account/items
/account/item/1
/account/item/1/edit
```

I know this is possible by performing string comparisons on request variables but was curious if there is a 'rails way' of determining this information.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem just now.. What I did is add a parameter to the scope:

```
scope '/me', me_scope: true do
  # ...
end
```

This way I can look it up in the controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def me_scope?
    params[:me_scope].eql? true
  end
end
```

Not the cleanest solution, but it works..

Comment: Be careful as this coud throw various `ActionController::UrlGenerationError`s in your tests.

Comment: I, too, was looking for (and expecting) a baked-in solution, but this seems to work easily enough.

Comment: @cseelus: Interesting!  Like what?